# Sound stopped working after update

Tags: sound

My sound stopped working after the first update came in for Elementary Loki.  The sound works fine if I boot in live mode from a jump drive.  I installed to hard drive 4/3/2017.  I've checked to make sure it's not muted in mixer.  I ran the command to make sure the sound card was recognized and it is there.  My sound card is on the mother board and is HDA Intel, Realtek ALC888.
I see several other posts but no fix.  One suggestion I saw was to add hda Intel generic to the alsa-base.conf.  That did not work for me either.
If anyone had this problem and found a fix I would greatly appreciate the info.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few months ago. In the end it was a bios update that fixed my sound issues. It was strange though because it didn't manifest until I received an elementary update.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem for last two days after update.  Installed pavucontrol and selected the external soundcard through it instead of through settings.  Worked.